# How to enable simple names for xampp htdocs projects on the browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, xampp, vhosts

I want to type cmssystem.test on the browser and direct me to my project in htdocs in xampp instead of localhost:8888/xampp/htdocs/cmsystem/abcdefghikl.......z

I tried adding the following directives to xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

[image: vhosts.conf]

And I also added to Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

[image: hosts]

But my browser directs me to my isp service provider asking me if I need help navigating the internet :/

Comment: You cannot have _two_ http hosts with the same name... You should get an error about this when trying to startup that http server. Please consult your http server's error log file.

Comment: I replaced the top cmssystem.test => localhost.test but still redirects me to my ISP main web page aking me if I need help navigating the interne

Comment: I will try this and report back how it went: https://blog.ign.uy/2010/mod-rewrite-urls-amigables-xampp

Comment: Aaaaaaand nope, with those directives on that link my Apache server would not even start

Comment: If your browser connects to the service provider then this is not an issue with your http server setup. Just a short test: can you reach it via IP address? If so, then your name resolution does not work. Have a try yourself: what does a `nslookup cmssystem.test` result in? Also you need to make sure results are not cached, so always use an anonymous tab or perform a _deep reload_ in your browser.

Comment: I am getting warmer. I emptied the cache from the browser  and changed the .test to .dev postfix on the window and apache config files. and now I get is Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from contactsapp.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and now the question is how to enable https:// on xampp

Comment: I found this https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/ will try this and keep playing follow the white rabbit.

Comment: It worked !!!!! so basically now adays browsers don't let you open a virtual host unless it has an SSL certificate.

Comment: Sorry but that is not true. Certainly any browser today will make a request to a http based URL without issues, _except_ from within an already loaded object that originated from a https based URL. But in general an http server's host can be operated both with or without encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it worked for me by creating an SSL cerificate for my domain name: https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/